What is the intuition for representations of the symmetric group?
What is the (physical) intuition for representations of the symmetric group? In particular, matrix coefficients of the Fourier coefficients corresponding to a representation.
For the cyclic group $C_n$ over $\mathbb{C}$, the group is abelian so representations are one dimensional and in one-to-one correspondence with units $\omega^k$ where $\omega = \exp(2 \pi i /n)$. That is, $\chi_k([j]) = \omega^{jk}$ where $\chi_k : C_n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. $0 \le k < n$ represents a frequency, telling us how fast to go around the unit circle. The same holds over $F_q$ as long as one has an $n^{th}$ root of unity $\alpha$ in place of $\omega$.
For the symmetric group $S_n$, representations are labeled by partitions $\lambda$ of $n$ which are in one-to-one correspondence with conjugacy classes of elements by cycle type. Representations can be constructed as Specht modules directly using a polytabloid basis. The group algebra $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$ decomposes as $\bigoplus_{\lambda}End_{\mathbb{C}}(V_{\lambda})$ via Maschke's theorem, and the Fourier transform is $\hat{f}(\lambda) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} f(\sigma)\lambda(\sigma)$. $\hat{f}(\lambda)$ is a $d_{\lambda} \times d_{\lambda}$ matrix, where $d_{\lambda}$ is the dimension of the representation, and $\hat{f}(\lambda)_{ij}$ is the $ij$ matrix element.
What do the basis elements on the right hand side represent? Like, what is $E(\lambda)_{ij}$, the elementary matrix with 1 in the $ij$-entry and 0 elsewhere?
